# What is this white foam under my tree?

Tags: identification, tree-care

South Florida.  Photo of tree that I can't identify.  It's been raining heavily for twelve hours and this white foam has appeared on the trunk, possibly due to water dripping.  What is this foam?

I've lived with this tree for 2 years and have never seen it happen before.  It is not there today now that it's dry.  I observed a piece of bark overhanging the area, channeling water to drip infrequently at the top portion of the bubbles, likely creating them somehow.  These do not appear to be eggs or a fungus.  When I hit them with a stick, they pop.  Has less the consistency of spittle bubbles; more like soap bubbles.  I do not use soap or detergent on my trees.

#### Full tree, foam to the left of the lawn gnome

[image: Full tree, foam to the left of the lawn gnome]

#### Closeup of foam

[image: Closeup of foam]

Comment: You might also have amphibians laying eggs - i.e. breeding tree fogs, etc. - particularly if you only notice it in the springtime. Some of the egg masses can be quite a foamy slime (though typically they are aiming for a pond/pool/puddle below rather than just dumping them down the tree.)

Comment: These are pretty clear bubbles...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this foam has appeared only during the heavy rain you've been experiencing, its a natural phenomenon. It occurs because some trees contain chemicals in the bark which can cause a soap like foam as the two interact, but this only occurs if the weather is very wet indeed; this phenomenon is not uncommon on pine trees in particular, but can happen with other trees.

If, though, you've noticed a particular area on the trunk foaming at other times, when it's not wet, check the area to make sure its not a slime flux, which indicates a bacterial infection. Info here http://www.wonderofeverydaynature.com/2016/03/26/155/

Comment: It is very wet, indubitably.  Been raining since midnight Eastern Standard Time last night, and so hevaily that my inground pool level gained four inches.

Comment: Ah well, that's certainly wet enough!

Comment: Any identification on the tree and potential chemicals that it produces which might cause foaming?

Comment: Was looking to identify it before I went away for a few days but was unsuccessful - does it flower or fruit in any way, and can you add a better picture of the foliage?

Comment: There are bunches of purple berries that stain the everliving crap out of the concrete below and drop into my pool.  The branches are long and soft; they can break off easily.  I believe the main photo is a compressed version of the full photo.

Comment: Yea, but I can't see the leaves 100% - so, whether they have toothed edges, any evidence of thorns or prickles on stems or leaves,  that's the sort of detail I'd like... knowing there are berries of some sort is helpful

Comment: This has continued to happen in that exact spot for over the last year whenever it rains.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this phenomenon on plants that were sprayed heavily with insecticidal soaps or dishsoap.  I've been in rains in Florida!  This could happen after spraying and the next hard rain will wash the soap off and  in the type of rain you get would certainly cause this bubbles!

Did you spray those trees?  Recently at all?  A surfactant is used for sprayed pesticides, sort of a 'sticker'.  That would cause the same effect as well.

If your trees have not been sprayed then we need to rethink this phenomenon.

Comment: I did not spray these trees and am leaning towards the natural phenomenon answer r.