# White spots on my bushes

Tags: identification, shrubs, insects

[image: Image of white spots on bush]

I was trimming my bushes today and I came upon these spots on several of the bushes. They look like they're largely at the junctures, and are even on one bush that I think died last year. Image searches are suggesting insect eggs. I don't know the type of bush - we inherited them with the house - but they usually flower with purple or white flowers.

Comment: Check this related question: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/32802/what-is-this-white-foam-under-my-tree It does not look like foam nests from spittlebugs which prefer softer and greener hosts. Perhaps remains from spiders. Cut off a typical example to make better photos with indication of size. Zooming and better light also will be helpful. Sometimes identification of the host is the key to the mystery.